# Difference between table_regions and table_areas

Tags: python-camelot

I read and re-read the doc, but I still don't understand the difference between, `table_regions` and `table_areas`
For me this two-parameter makes the same thing..., but the doc specifies then `table_regions` work on `approximate region`.

I think the doc can be more specific about what means `approximate region` and what is the difference with `table_areas`

I hope someone can explain to me clearly the difference between these two functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggested the introduction of this feature (https://github.com/atlanhq/camelot/issues/209).

Using *table_areas*, you can specify the actual coordinates of the table boundary.
Camelot finds a table which have exactly these coordinates.

Instead, using *table_regions*, you can specify the region of the page where Camelot search for tables. Camelot finds all the tables which reside inside this region.

Feel free to ask for clarification.